# Purely spectral algorithms for the minimum spanning tree problem

Tags: reference-request, spectral-graph-theory

There are many algorithms that address the MST problem, from classical (Boruvka, Prim, Kruskal), optimal ([Pettie et al.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.43.2257&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) to their distributed variants ([Bader et al.](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~bader/papers/MST-JPDC.pdf)).

However, I fail to find any references to algorithms that might use spectral properties to algebraically arrive at a suitable representation of the MST (e.g. the set of edges, the adjacency or Laplacian matrix of the MST).

Are there any such algorithms or rationales (proofs) why they don't exist?